# Get index of set from number within it

Tags: elementary-number-theory

(Sorry this is probably tagged wrong, but I don't even know most of these terms)

I have sets of numbers that increase like so:

set 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6

set 2: 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18

set 3: 19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36

Basically, $6n$ numbers in a given set.

But all I have is $i$, a number in a set. Is there a way to get which set this number part of without additional information? If it were just 6 numbers in a set, I'd use $\lceil i/6 \rceil$ but for the life of me I cannot work this one out.

Comment: You are on the right track. First compute $\,n=\lceil i/6\rceil\,$ and then use [OEIS sequence 2024](https://oeis.org/A002024) "n appears n times; a(n) = floor(sqrt(2n) + 1/2)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sequence of *triangular numbers*, which is the sequence $1,1+2,1+2+3,...$. It's a famous exercise to calculate these, I'll describe it for you and you can work out the solution from there. Then, to find the set index $n$ of a number $i$, you'd need to solve a quadratic equation - feel free to ask if you get stuck.

There is a famous story of Gauss finding a shortcut to calculate the $n$th triangular number, while he was still at primary school. One day, when his teacher was frustrated with him, his teacher told him to add up all the numbers from 1 to 100, hoping it would take him a while. But 30 seconds later, Gauss came back with the solution, much to his teacher's chagrin. Gauss' trick was to take all the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,98,99,100$, and divide them into pairs of numbers which added up to the same sum. Then he counted how many pairs there were, and multiplied the common sum by the number of pairs to get his answer quickly. See if you can work out his formula.